# Restrict tappable area of picker within a List

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui

List expands the tappable area of a button/picker for the whole row. With buttons, changing the style to .plain restricts the tappable area, but can't figure out how to restrain the picker.

```
    enum Selection: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
        case first, second, third
        var id: String { return self.rawValue }
    }
    @State private var variable: Selection = Selection.first
    
    var body: some View {
            List {
                    VStack {
                        Picker("Selection: ", selection: $variable) {
                            ForEach(Selection.allCases, id: \.id) { i in
                                Text(i.id).tag(i)
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Button("First") {
                            print("first")
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        
                        Button("Second") {
                            print("second")
                        }
                }
            }
    }
```

Is there a way to restrict the tappable area, or is list just not meant to be used in this manner.

Comment: There are many limitations with the Picker, and often times you have to implement your own picker because of that. Don't know if there's a simpler solution for this particular issue, but quite possibly you have to implement your own

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how I missed it, but .pickerStyle(.menu) achieves the goal.